# How does SendGrid verify that an email was "delivered", and how can I do the same when using Gmail SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, sendgrid

SendGrid is able to track if an email ["... was accepted by the receiving server"](https://sendgrid.com/docs/glossary/deliveries/).

How would one go about doing this in an application that uses Gmail SMTP servers rather than SendGrid? (For example, a NodeJS application that uses nodemailer, or a Ruby-on-Rails app that uses Action Mailer, to send email through Gmail SMTP)

Answer (score 1):

Google's different levels of paid G Suite offerings have logging you can use: [Track message delivery with Email Log Search (google.com)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2618874?hl=en).

If you're not paying for G Suite and you're trying to build a way to collect statistics yourself, that becomes more tricky. Email service providers will generally count an "open" using something like a click-through on a link in the email (linked back to a property you control), or the loading of an image in the email (again, loaded from a property you control). You can read more about how ESP email open rates work here: [The Science Behind Email Open Rates (and How to Get More People to Read Your Emails) (superoffice.com)](https://www.superoffice.com/blog/email-open-rates/)

Comment: Thank you for telling me about GSuite Email Log Search. The data in there is interesting, but I'm looking for something more programmer-friendly that will allow me to examine delivery rates without manual intervention

Comment: Also want to mention: I already understand open-rate tracking. I'm looking for advice on email delivery tracking (like SendGrid does) specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail's SMTP servers don't report email delivery, only if there's a bounce. Google is somewhat closed with that, only paid users in G Suite can actually see the detailed delivery status using the Email Log Search tool.

Hope this helps.